# Why should I use `required` in DOM while I set the field as required in FormBuilder?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

In Angular Reactive Form document guidelines when a form is built by `FormBuilder` and set for example:

```
this.fb.group({
  firstName: ['', Validators.required]
});
```

Why we should use `required` attribute DOM again:

```
<input type="text" formControlName="firstName" required>
```

Is there any way to read form properties from FormBuiler and omit `required` attribute from DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the  docs there is a statement regarding this

> Use these HTML5 validation attributes in combination with the built-in
>   validators provided by Angular's reactive forms. Using these in
>   combination prevents errors when the expression is changed after the
>   template has been checked.

This is actually suggested to create a foolproof validation logic. Also, mind that the HTML you are writing will be compiled to js ie, it's not your normal HTML

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you'd be given a warning when you're mixing Reactive Forms and DOM attributes in the template.

> Is there any way to read form properties from FormBuiler and omit required attribute from DOM?

I think there is a way, you can used a [**boxed value**](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L1211-L1220):

```js
firstName: [{ value: '', disabled: true | false }, ...]

// Or

firstName: this.fb.control({ value: '', disabled: true | false }, ...)
```

Comment: I put complete syntax. But I think misunderstanding occurred. Andrei we talk about 'Validators.required' not 'disabled'

Comment: I'm sorry, I was thinking of completely something else while answering. I don't think that's possible, but if you already have it with reactive forms, why would you need it in the DOM as well?

Comment: If you look at https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms you will see <input type="text" formControlName="firstName" required> while couple line above it is declare firstName: ['', Validators.required],